ISS deorbit or raise?
How much more expensive would it be to move up the iss to a rare orbit where it would pose no risk to other space ventures, and not decay much due to atmospheric drag, to become a “museum” (or ship wreck) that future explorers could visit in a few hundred years?

Another possible duplicate: Deorbit ISS vs. Preserve ISS as raw material

I will say that there have been plenty of news articles on this subject, as well as questions on this site, and the answer is that it would be both much more expensive, more difficult, and less practical. Right now, space tourism is not at the point where museums are at all feasible.
